# What does `exchange' mean in this sentence?

Tags: nouns

I am trying to understand an English passage about beauty and the Trinity:

> We can define beauty as “that which, when seen, pleases.” But there is something going on at a deeper level—--an exchange—--that is a mystery. This is because both the Trinity and the transcendentals are known and experienced only relationally.

I'm struggling understanding 'an exchange' between the dashes. What part of the sentence is decorated by the phrase enclosed in dashes? If the word 'exchange' means 'changing one thing with another,' what is it changing with what?

Comment: Hard to say with any certainty, but it sounds like the author feels that the person seeing somehow "projects" his pleasure back to the object being observed.  "An exchange" appears to be referencing/defining "*something* going on at a deeper level".

Comment: Perhaps the aesthetic feeling, which is exchanged between the onlooker and the object of beauty, rather than the object of beauty itself that pleases the seer.

Comment: Parentheticals are nonessential. They provide nothing aside from optional clarification. In this case, the meaning of the nonessential information isn't completely clear. But it doesn't need to be in order for the rest of the sentence to be grammatical. Interpreting what it means here is subjective.

Comment: Might it matter whether the point was "We can define beauty as 'that which pleases'?"

When there's "an exchange… that is a mystery" can you explain or should we guess how that's because both the Trinity and the transcendentals are known and experienced only relationally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe "exchange" here is being used in the sense of communication.

Common examples of "exchange" used in this sense include (for example):

"We had a brief *exchange* in the corridor" (here, it's being used as a synonym for a conversation or discussion).

"We *exchanged* ideas over lunch." (here, it's being used to refer to swapping ideas in a conversation).

Judging by that (all too brief) excerpt you quoted, I think the author was alluding to a beautiful object communicating something (an aesthetic sense of wonder, perhaps?) to the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

The dashes surround an appositive.   The phrase "an exchange" is a restatement -- an emphatic parenthetical clarification, in this case -- of the preceding phrase "something going on at a deeper level".

From the excerpt you've provided, we have no idea what things are exchanged.   Given that this exchange is characterized as a mystery, it seems likely that the author also has no idea.